# mysql insert into a specific row

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and would like to ask a question - hopefully someone can help me. Here is my current code:

```
    <? 
     $title=$_POST['name']; 
     $text=$_POST['text']; 
     mysql_connect("localhost", "test", "test") or die(mysql_error()); 
     mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$location')"); 
     Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; 
     ?>
```

I would like to achieve that the data inserted goes into the column where my ID is 1.

Thank you very much,
Nareen

Comment: so you read mysql tutorial about SELECT and INSERT but didn't about UPDATE?

Comment: That table can't have an ID column

Comment: Do you have an ID field that is set to auto increment?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need an [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `data` SET `field1`='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."', `field2`='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', `field3`='".mysql_real_escape_string($location)."' WHERE `ID` = 1");
```

You should always use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) when data comes from users (for instance when using `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST, etc.) to make sure it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

Well then you should be doing an update, so long as your ID already exists.  e.g.

```
UPDATE data D
SET D.YourColumn = @value
WHERE D.ID = @id;
```

...otherwise nothing will update.  Might help to read a bit about the `UPDATE` statement -- I've heard it's an essential piece of knowledge to database development. ;)